# Comparing iterator and const_iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, constants, stdmap

I have a method which finds the particular position in a map and 'returns' this via an iterator reference:

```
bool Func(const int searchKey, MyMap::iterator& iter) const {
    iter = _map.upper_bound(searchKey);  // Compiler error: comparing non-const iterator and const iterator

    const bool found = iter != _map.begin();

    if(something){
        --_map;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I am getting a compiler error because `std::upper_bound()` is returning an `std::const_iterator` and comparing this with an `std::iterator`.

Should I 'cast' the return value of `upper_bound()` to be non-const?

Comment: Just for clarity - is the `_map` a member variable and this a member function?

Comment: What's `_map`? Post a [mcve], please.

Answer (score 5):

No, you should not cast the return value of `upper_bound`. You should remove the `const` qualifier on the function. The function is providing non-const access to an element of the map (via the out parameter), so it should not be const.

Comment: Agreed, also note the "--_map;" I have no idea what it does, but it modifies the "_map" which ought to be a member variable.

Comment: It was better to make my iterators const_iterator because I wasn't modifying the value.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> bool Func(const int searchKey, MyMap::iterator& iter) const {
>     iter = _map.upper_bound(searchKey); // Compiler error: comparing non-const iterator and const iterator
> ```

This method is marked `const`, but you are returning a position in the `_map` using a *non*-`const` iterator (the `iter` parameter), giving to the caller *non*-const access to the map's elements, thus violating the `const` method specification.

Either remove `const` from `Func` declaration, or return a `MyMap::const_iterator&`, depending on what kind of access to the map's elements you want to give to the caller.

Or you may write two overloads for `Func`: a `const` one and a non-`const` one, returning a `MyMap::const_iterator` and `MyMap::iterator` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

is your map const qualified ?

if your map is const-qualified, std::map::upper_bound will return a const iterator, if it's not it should return an iterator